# Does philosophy suffer from an ad populum bias?

Tags: fallacies, theology, philosophy-of-religion, cognitive-bias, popular-science

It seems to me that positions in philosophy are taken more seriously depending on how many people believe in them. For example, someone who believes in a monotheistic God is taken a bit more seriously than someone who believes in polytheism who is in turn taken more seriously than anyone who believes in Santa Claus. Even supposedly sophisticated philosophies such as Kant’s transcendental idealism are taken seriously. But readers of him still don’t know or agree upon what it even means. Is the disagreement due to the complex hard to understand nature of the argument or just the mere result of mental masturbation over nothing?

Is there really any difference in evidence between concepts like these? If not, why is one dismissed as a joke and the other treated with such sophistication? Anyone can write a book about all kinds of attributes of Santa Claus, perhaps call it Clausian Simplicity instead of Divine Simplicity, or define his existence in ways no one can comprehend or even verify the coherence of such as “timeless, eternal, bodiless minds” and call it a day.

This isn’t meant to mock. It’s a genuine question about why one is expected to have a whole load of sophisticated knowledge on theist arguments for example compared to some concept that we all find ridiculous like Santa Claus

Comment: Of course! If you compare the entries in SEP/IEP for American/British philosophers vs Japanese/Thai/Senegalese/Peruvian/Pakistani/..... you either must conclude that God distributed IQ very very unequally. Or else your question is trivially affirmative. Take your pick

Comment: The more believers, the fewer remain to doubt them. For Santa Claus, their credibility must be taken into account – young children believe what they are *told*. There lies a parallel with religions. Most believers haven't had a revelation but been *told* what to believe, with huge societal pressure to conform. Some religions are of their time, with beliefs unable to move forwards with the expansion of human knowledge. For example, the idea that Earth was created 6000 years ago, and anything that seems older is intended to look that way: is very open to mockery, quite justifiably.

Comment: @WeatherVane "Had you been born in X, you would likely believe X-belief, not Y-belief" is true, but it's not an argument against Y-belief. Try for comparison: "Had you been born in Tikrit, you would likely be a believer in the six-day creation, not 21st century geology."

Comment: @gs if everybody in Tikrit believes in the 6-day creation, how does that invalidate what one single other person believes to be true? Witness Copernicus, Galileo, Darwin.

Comment: @WeatherVane That is the point: being born somewhere else would make you likely to believe something else is true and also irrelevant to the truth or falsehood of whatever is being discussed.

Comment: Then I don't get what point you are trying to make. I was not arguing against your "Y-belief". I wasn't born in Tikrit, but I wasn't born "somewhere else".

Comment: Philosophy is an on-going discussion. If you want to join in, you need to join the existing discussion. Which means you need to read at least some of the texts that others have read and are now discussing.  Nobody can read **everything**. Choices have to be made. That doesn't mean that new or neglected, philosophy can't be introduced into the discussion.

Comment: @LudwigV This isn’t science. Why should any philosopher’s thoughts bear any more importance than mine? Name me the philosophy that justifies that

Comment: @Baby_philosopher That comment wasn't science, nor yet philosophy. It wasn't even about which philosophers are important. It was suggesting things you could do to strike up a conversation with a philosopher about philosophy. If you want to talk to a musician about music, it is a good idea to know something about it. Ditto philosophy. Ditto science. You can just ignore me if you don't like the suggestion. I won't take offence.

Answer (score 1):

The key concept here might be meme theory, searching for what attributes and events make one idea more successful in replicating than another idea, even regardless of their individual truthfulness or evidence support.

In the case of Kant’s transcendental idealism, the point is that even if not understanding it, the problem that Kant found and tries to solve can be understood, and it can be obvious that there is no simple or other solution to it.

While there may be some mental masturbation involved in discussing this, nobody becomes the highlight of a party by talking about Kant.

What makes such writing special is that it gained lots of attention without any cult or other organization backing it, in comparison to many other writings you never heard about and never will.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer is trivially yes in the sense that 'taken more seriously' boils down to meaning 'taken seriously by more people', which you can confuse with 'more popular'.

That said, the study of philosophy- like the study of the subjects such as literature- has an inherent streak of conservatism which arises from the fact that it is passed on from teacher to student. As a consequence, what is deemed 'great' philosophy or literature is an established convention, a default categorisation taken for granted. When I went Birkenhead library in the 1970s, the philosophy shelves contained classic works of philosophy. Why do you suppose that was? Did the librarian make a fresh trawl of all the books available to decide which were most valuable, or did they just stock the books because they had heard of them? People read Kant partly because they assume they should if they are to conform with the default expectations, just as people read classic literature.